# How to run two ajax calls in one plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, soundcloud

I am building a javascript plugin that pulls in data using the SoundCloud api via PHP, then I have a jquery plugin wrapper ($fn.plugin) around an ajax call pulling in the GET variables.  Works great and is feeding a soundcloud player fine.

However, I want to extend this plugin by giving the option to pull in song data via an RSS feed as well.  My question is, should I wrap both ajax calls in an if else?  Then set a variable to true.

Something like:

```
var rss = true

if (rss == true){
    // run ajax rss call
}else {
    // run ajax call to soundcloud api
}
```

I guess I'm interested in how others would go about this.

EDIT: ADDED MORE CODE

```
 $.fn.ed_audio_list = function(options) {

    // default options.
    var settings = $.extend({
        // These are the defaults.
            color: red,
            title: 'My Song Player',
            rssURL: false
    }, options );

    if (rssURL !== false){
        // run ajax rss call
    }else {
            // run ajax call to soundcloud api
        }

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Seems like an ordinary way to do it, what alternatives might there be? If you anticipate eventually having lots of different choices, you might use an object whose keys are source names, and values are functions that send the appropriate AJAX call.

Comment: Depending on the format of the returned data, you'll either have to do it with 2 separate AJAX calls (one in the if, one in the else), or you can set the URL to call in the if/else, then make the AJAX call after that if you're going to handle the data the same way for both URLs.

Comment: I actually have it all working.  The only problem I'm having is checking to see if there is a value for rssURL.  If someone doesn't specify a URL for an RSS feed, then I want to run the SoundCloud API (in this case the else() statement)